# Tor and Direct Download

Tags: anonymity

Does downloading from a Direct Download (DD) site like Rapidgator through TOR ensures anonymity like browsing any other web site ?

If so, is there a way to ensure download managers like Mipony connect to the DD sites through Tor ?

Thanks

Comment: can Mipony use proxy (https,http,socks) if so, yes tor is useful.